# ¿Por qué la API de WhatsApp no lee las variables?

Tags: javascript, api, whatsapp

estoy enviando un mensaje de texto común, ejemplo

```
<a href={"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5412345678&amp;text=Hola"}>
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona correctamente, el inconveniente surgió cuando intento usar variables

```
<a href={"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5412345678&amp;text= El%20Producto%20es" + name.producto}>
```

También intenté lo siguiente sin ningún éxito

```
<a href={`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5412345678&amp;text= El%20Producto%20es ${name.producto}`>
```

Cuando intento llamar a la API, generando la URL con variables; deja de funcionar.

Si alguien sabe una solución oportuna estaría agradecido de que me lo diga, muchas gracias.

Comment: Se ven claramente **los espacios**. Una URL **no puede tener espacios**.

Comment: Añadiendo a eso, WhatsApp no ve las variables. Tu programa usa las variables para componer una URL, la URL se usa para crear una conexión, el servidor de WhatsApp recibe una petición. No sabe ni le importa cómo se creó la URL.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu primer ejemplo funciona debería funcionar también poner una variable. Te sugiero que pruebes primero de la manera más estándar posible:

De la página de Mozilla se puede usar `fixedEncodeURIComponent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, "%2A");
}
```

Luego usar esa función para "escapar" el texto que agregas (así los espacios son `%20`, etc):

```
<a href={"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5412345678&amp;text="+
    fixedEncodeURIComponent("El Producto es " + name.producto)}>
```

Así no aparecen espacios ni signos no permitidos en la URL.